# ActiveMQ consumers vanishing

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We are using ActiveMQ 5.10 broker with following configuration

- JVM heap 48G out of which 70% allocated for memoryUsage
- 70G storage and 1G for temp

we are using Apache camel 2.10.2 route to consume messages from queue.
After receiving message, we create ~40k smaller messages/ received message and publish them onto another queue using `asyncSend` using spring's jmstemplate.

We have configured different `connectionFactory` for consumer and producer which work on pooledconnection

As we generate millions of messages onto the queue, we have configured `producerWindowSize` on the producerConnectionFactory

Problem:
After few hours of running we generate ~10 million messages onto the broker and consumers on the queue starts disappearing. Eventually there are no consumers and our system comes to halt.
The only work around we have as of now is to restart the application

Question:
What will be the behavior of `asyncSend` producer with `producerWindoeSize`, in case broker restarts?

**Update :**
I am able to reproduce this issue by restarting the broker, when camel consumers are sending those millions of messages on the queue.

I am planning to set `recoveryInterval` on the camel `JmsConfiguration`, please post your views on this.

**Update:**

I was able to capture a thread dump on the jvm on which consumers are vanishing. 
The threads are blocked on producer window, waitForSpace().

```
Camel (CamelContext) thread #573 - JmsConsumer[RequestQueue]" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000011ded000 nid=0x156c in Object.wait() [0x000000005b69d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor) 
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) 
        at org.apache.activemq.usage.MemoryUsage.waitForSpace(MemoryUsage.java:67) 
        - locked <0x00000006a0bfc058> (a java.lang.Object) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:271) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:212) 
        at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:79) 
        - locked <0x00000006a0bfbec8> (a org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer) 
        at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:67) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:589) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:569) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:546) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:543) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:620)
```

This wait never finishes, even if memory usage returns to normal.
I am using activeMQ 5.7 client libraries

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4512

But wanted to know, Is there any valid work around? Also even If I reduce my consumers to 1 I observe this issue.

Comment: There must be some kind of log on the Camel side why a consumer stops. Try to find out what is happening from that perspective. It's very hard to guess what's wrong out of the memory settings alone.

Comment: @Petter updated observation

Comment: What about camel/client logs?

Comment: @Petter Nordlander updated with thread trace

Comment: Ok, I see. What about an update of AMQ version?

Comment: Wont be possible to update activemq, as we are tied in with camel,karaf